# Impossible to publish an article in only one language

Tags: django, django-cms

I am a beginner in django cms and I have recuperated a project in this language and I find a bug without an answer.

The site is multilingual (French, English) and same for the blog. When an article is created in French I find myself having the article in French version in the list of articles on the English version of the site (in the list of English articles there are the French articles).

I hope I've been clear, do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: The problem is clear but can't help you without taking a look at the code. Can you show us the code of the view which lists the articles?

Comment: @SaadullahAleem it takes default view of djangocms_blog package to list the articles :/